# Selecting min values in SQL table when column < 0, and max values when column > 0

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I have a SQL table like this:

```
Ticker    Return       Shares
AGJ        2.20         1265
ATA        1.78        698
ARS        9.78        10939
ARE       -7.51       -26389
AIM        0.91        1758
ABT        10.02       -5893
AC        -5.73       -2548
ATD        6.51        7850
AP         1.98        256
ALA       -9.58        8524
```

So essentially, a table of stocks I've longed/shorted.

I want to find the top 4 best performers in this table, so the shorts (shares < 0) who have the lowest return, and the longs (shares > 0) who have the highest return.
Essentially, returning this:

```
Ticker    Return       Shares
ARS        9.78        10939
ARE       -7.51       -26389
AC        -5.73       -2548
ATD        6.51        7850
```

How would I be able to write the query that lets me do this?

Or, if it's easier, if there are any pandas functions that would do the same thing if I turned this table into a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select top (4) t.*
from t
order by (case when shares < 0 then - [return] else [return] end) desc;
```

Comment: this will return __all__ rows, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks! But, I get this error when using this:
 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'return'.

Comment: @MLiu . . .`return` is the name of *your* column.  This is the simplest solution to your question.  You can add a `TOP (x)` to return just x rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Oops.. don't know why I didn't catch that! This is great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas solution:

```
In [134]: df.loc[(np.sign(df.Shares)*df.Return).nlargest(4).index]
Out[134]:
  Ticker  Return  Shares
2    ARS    9.78   10939
3    ARE   -7.51  -26389
7    ATD    6.51    7850
6     AC   -5.73   -2548
```

Explanation:

```
In [137]: (np.sign(df.Shares)*df.Return)
Out[137]:
0     2.20
1     1.78
2     9.78
3     7.51
4     0.91
5   -10.02
6     5.73
7     6.51
8     1.98
9    -9.58
dtype: float64

In [138]: (np.sign(df.Shares)*df.Return).nlargest(4)
Out[138]:
2    9.78
3    7.51
7    6.51
6    5.73
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked perfectly.

Comment: @MLiu, glad I could help :)